# Bulk download Sci-Hub papers using a list of URLs

Tags: download, pdf, open-access

I wonder whether it is possible to bulk download  papers with Sci-Hub using a list of urls stored as file. i want to automate the download because i need 1570 article

Comment: WGet or WinHTTrack. Note that you are also not saying which OS and what price.

Comment: Since sci-hub.tw describes itself as a pirate website, you may be pushing the rules here, but searching for sci-hub torrent yielded a few hits.

Comment: @BarryCarter legality != morality. i highly encourage all to use sci-hub to get around open access issues, particularly in open science and regarding open data.

Comment: @albert I may agree with you (I believe in large scale copyright reform), but by "pushing the rules here", I meant Stack Exchange's rules, as Stack Exchange has a fairly strong no-piracy/no-illegal-activity policy.

Comment: @BarryCarter i had no idea. my bad entirely. apologies.

Answer (score 3):

You can bulk download/automate Sci-Hub files with a list of URLs using [wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) and a list of URLs (one per line) in a text file. In the following example, I have a text file (`list.txt`) that looks like this:

```
https://backup.sci-hub.tw/6024/6a24172bc2d8aa7ed9f2697aaa2963a4/10.2307@27732699.pdf
https://moscow.sci-hub.tw/3415/665548c34ac048f176f74bd9d7041a83/10.2307@20486079.pdf
```

Then use `wget` from terminal/command line with the following command:

```
wget -i list.txt
```

Sci-Hub URLs typically embed the PDF, so I think gathering a list of URLs is going to be the actual difficult part here.